# Using Func Delegate to set DateTime fields of the class

Tags: c#

I have a class with two DateTime fields, I want to have one shared method to set both of them. Would it be possible somehow to do so with Func Delegate?

```
    private void SetDateTimeField(MyClass class, Func<SupportTicket, DateTime> selector, DateTime date)
    {
      //using selector to select a field of the class and set date parameter to it
    }
```

and then use it like:

```
SetDateTimeField(class, c => c.DateTimeField1, DateTime.UtcNow);
SetDateTimeField(class, c => c.DateTimeField2, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

This question less about practicality of it, but rather understanding how to do it. Is it possible?

Comment: lambdas return values not references

Comment: Not like that, no. You could use that to *fetch* the values of properties, but if you want to *set* the values, you'd need an `Action<SupportTicket, DateTime>` instead, e.g. `(c, dt) => c.DateTimeField1 = dt;`

Comment: Won't work because `SetDateTimeField()` doesn't have a reference to the variable. Wouldn't it be easier to just do `c.DateTimeField1 = DateTime.UtcNow; c.DateTimeField2 = DateTime.UtcNow;`?

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question, it should get you started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373142/how-to-assign-a-value-from-memberexpression-to-a-field-according-to-another-memb You will most probably need either expressions or reflection/Reflection.Emit to achieve your goal. Please note that you will also need instance_of_class rather than "class" as a parameter, unless I misunderstood your question

Comment: Its possible with a [MemberExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression?view=net-7.0) to retrieve the property name and setter (if available) through reflection and set the value but  that's mostly done in stuff like GUI libraries when binding form fields to properties of an entity

Comment: I know this doesn't look the way you want it to, obviously, but why not just do `SetDateTimeField(class, collection.Select(c => c.DateTimeField1), DateTime.UtcNow);` making the second parameter an `IEnumerable<T>`? IEnumerable is very intimately tied to collections so this seems comprehensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DateTime fields are actually fields (not properties), you can use `ref`.

```cs
var c = new MyClass();

MyClass.SetDateTimeField(c, c => ref c.dt1, DateTime.Now);
MyClass.SetDateTimeField(c, c => ref c.dt2, DateTime.Now);

public class MyClass {
    public DateTime dt1;
    public DateTime dt2;
    
    public delegate ref DateTime Selector(MyClass c);
    
    public static void SetDateTimeField(MyClass c, Selector sel, DateTime dt) {
        sel(c) = dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a function, pass a function expression. You can then derive the property from the expression and set its value.

```
public class SupportTicket
{
    public DateTime DT1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DT2 { get; set; }
}


private static void SetDateTimeField<TObj, TProp>(TObj obj, Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>> selectorExpr, TProp date)
{
    // Get the body of the function as a member access expression
    MemberExpression memberExpr = selectorExpr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpr != null)
    {
        // Get the property from the member access expression and set the value
        MemberInfo memberInfo = memberExpr.Member;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = memberInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty(memberInfo.Name);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, date);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("You must use a member access expression");
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
SupportTicket ticket = new SupportTicket();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
SetDateTimeField(ticket, e => e.DT1, dt);
SetDateTimeField(ticket, e => e.DT2, dt);

Console.WriteLine(ticket.DT1);
Console.WriteLine(ticket.DT2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This answers appears to be the most about what the OP asked; *understanding how to do it*.  I would also add that the understanding needs to discuss using [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-7.0) and [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to fully grasp the *how* it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a property based on name you can do it like this:

```
private void SetDateTimeField(MyClass classX, String selector, DateTime dateX)
{
  //using selector to select a field of the class and set date parameter to it
  var prop = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(selector);

  prop.SetValue(classX, dateX);


}

SetDateTimeField(class, "DateTimeField1", DateTime.UtcNow);
SetDateTimeField(class, "DateTimeField2", DateTime.UtcNow);
```